# SELECT not working for Ruby-mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby

quick question - my ruby application is freezing at the query command in the below script. Any ideas why?

Cheers
Martin

```
require "mysql"
con = Mysql.new('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password', 'database')
con.select_db('database')
queryresult = con.query("SELECT * FROM table")
#puts queryresult.inspect
queryresult.free
con.close
```

Comment: Do you have a gazillion rows in that table?

Comment: Just the one, I am using the latest ruby-mysql and the latest sql server

Comment: So, is it SQL Server or MySQL? Also, why don't you try `mysql2` gem? It's faster and better.

Comment: Yeah sorry its mysql server. I'll try the mysql2 gem and see how that goes, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Is your table really named "table"?

Try using a different table name - MySQL sometimes has quirks when it tries to parse reserved words.